# Laravel API with React. Fetch 'POST' responds with 401: "Unauthorized"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, fetch-api

I cannot seem to figure out how to POST new data to the database.
I have a form with a `handleSubmit`:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const {to_user, hours_spend, hours_max} = this.state

  fetch('api/klippekort', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': this.props.csrf_token,
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    to_user,
    hours_spend,
    hours_max
  })      
}).then(res => console.log(res))
}
```

The result I get in console is:

> Response { type: "basic", url: "http://localhost/api/klippekort", redirected: false, status: 401, ok: false, statusText: "Unauthorized", headers: Headers, bodyUsed: false }

CSRF token is set correctly:

```
x-csrf-token:   n9itPhKayehfKFTlmlq6xDn
```

Route is set as well in api.php (no middleware here)

```
Route::post('klippekort','KlippekortController@store');
```

I also tried disabling CSRF token all together in App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken:

```
protected $except = [
  'api/*'
];
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Its not csrf related, its related to api group. Open up your route service provider to learn more.

Comment: `middleware('auth:api')` thats what is giving you 401 response...

Comment: Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});


Route::post('klippekort','KlippekortController@store');
That shouldn't have any effect right?

Comment: I get same error when i comment it out.. and I am logged in as admin?

Comment: run the following: `php artisan route:list` find the route you having trouble with and see its middleware

Comment: hmm yes; POST                           | api/klippekort                                      |                                  | App\Http\Controllers\KlippekortController@store                           | api,auth              :                                                                                                                                    So I have that middleware defined ' somewhere' in my code I guess?

Comment: As I've already stated in first comment: its defined in route service provider, or better yet in kernel.php. Check that out.

Comment: Oki, thanks... Should have enough to somehow resolve this issue. I hope

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kyslik I figured out it was the middleware that responded with unauthorized.

In my controller i had

```
__contruct() { $this->middleware('auth') }
```

Once removed, issue is resolved